# (Swift) how to use Segue pass textField to TableViewCell under another ViewController?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I wonder how to pass the textField to my customTableViweCell. Please, someone help me! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vA5fo.jpg)

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue" {
    let nextVC = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
    let dest = nextVC.topViewController as! ViewController
    let ind = sender as! customTableViewCell

    let nTxt = nameTxt.text?.description
    let pTxt = phoneTxt.text?.description
    let eTxt = emailTxt.text?.description
    let dTxt = dobTxt.text?.description
    ind.lb1 = "\(nTxt!)"
    ind.lb2 = "\(pTxt!)"
    ind.lb3 = "\(eTxt!)"
    ind.lb4 = "\(dTxt!)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`segue.destination` will contain the destination view controller.  You should cast it to your custom view controller that will be presented.  That view controller, should have properties defined that will be used to build that view.  You should set those properties in `prepare` so that when the destination view controller loads the view, those properties can be used to update the view components.  Here's an example.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue" {
        let dest = segue.destination as? YourCustomViewController
        dest?.customProp = someValue
    }
}
```

Comment: let dest = segue.destination as? YourCustomViewController
dest?.lb1 = "\(nTxt)"  error="Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'lb1'. "

the value 'lb1' I have drop under "customerTableViewCell", and "customerTableViewCell" is under "ViewCotroller" how I link it?

Comment: lb1 has to be a non-private member of your custom view controller class.

Comment: lb1 I have drop it to customerTableViewCell, it is not a view controller class. do you have any Idea? how to pass the textField to customTableViewCell